# How do I implement a useModal hook properly

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to implement a useModal hook which I can incorporate in my React App. The code seems to work, until I use the hook in a different component.

I added the code to a sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/usemodal-hook-asfvn-b42nsw

Answer (score 1):

The hook you've written lets you reuse code, but it will not share state. Every component that calls `useModal` creates its *own* `showModal` and `body` states. When SomeComponent calls setShowModal, that only affects SomeComponent, not anything else.

In react, the standard way to share states between components is to [lift the state up](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/sharing-state-between-components) into a component that is a parent of all the components that need it. Then you use props to pass it down. If props is combersome, you might use context instead.

So, you could have App contain the state, and then pass it down as a prop to SomeComponent:

```
export default function App() {
  const { body, showModal, setShowModal } = useModal();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Modal showModal={showModal} body={body} setShowModal={setShowModal} />
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <SomeComponent setShowModal={setShowModal}/>
    </div>
  );
}

// ...

export default function SomeComponent({ setShowModal }) {
  return <div onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}>SHOW MODAL</div>;
}
```

If state + props/context is inconvenient, you could consider using one of the many libraries that exist to do global state management. Eg, [Redux](https://redux.js.org/), [Recoil](https://recoiljs.org/), [Jotai](https://jotai.org/), [Zustand](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zustand).